# how to print all the undefined function calls along with file name from shared object?

Tags: c, nm

I am trying to print all the Undefined function calls from a shared object file along with file name.

I tried with "nm" command, It print all the undefined function calls .But could not get the file name.

Example:

```
  bash$ nm -u my_test.so
  :
   U _ZNSs4_Rep20_S_empty_rep_storageE@@GLIBCXX_3.4
  :
```

Environment : Ubuntu 18.04 , X86 Arch (Intel processor)

Comment: which platform?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala update the question

Comment: Also,, do you want the .c file name or...?

Comment: Yes. only .c file used

Comment: Why do you ask, and what is your exact motivation? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54141208/edit) your question to tell why do you need that. Looks like some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I updated the question. I wan to list all the undefined functions with file name from a shared object.

Comment: By definition, an undefined function has no source file. Maybe you want to list all the occurrences of *calls* to undefined (external) functions, with the source file location of each call, and that is a very different question

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch. Sorry. You are right. I want to print all the undefined function calls and the file name where this  functions are called.

Comment: You'll better edit your question again to improve it. Your question is so unclear that I did downvote it

Comment: How much undefined functions do you have? A dozen, or many thousands? And why do you need to find all the calls to each of them? Again, your question should explain the actual problem you have.

Comment: Even with the recent edit, your question lacks motivation and smells badly as some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Please take some time to add a few paragraphs explaining the real issue you are tackling with. Without that, your question is unclear.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Sure. I will take some time and update more info.thanks

Comment: Then hurry up,  because your unclear question could be closed before you improve it

Answer (score 2):

Study in details the specification of the [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) format (which is the format used by debugging information on Linux). So you could extract the information (but it is not exactly simple) by parsing the DWARF inside your [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) binary.

Consider looking inside the source code of [Ian Taylor's libbacktrace](https://github.com/ianlancetaylor/libbacktrace). It is doing this extraction of file name from DWARF inside ELF.

Perhaps your real problem is getting precise backtrace information, and then that `libbacktrace` is exactly what you need!

You might also use `gdb` : it is [extensible](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Extending-GDB.html) and scriptable in Python (or Guile) and you could write your own specialized script.

Perhaps you'll better solve your real problem with some [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) working when you *compile* your code.

Read [*How to write shared libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) by Drepper and read more about ELF.

You could for example collect all the undefined symbols in your shared library using `nm` (or [`readelf`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/readelf.html)). Then a second script will find the occurrences of these in your source code. It could be even a simple [awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/) script (or some `for` shell loop using `grep`), or something as sophisticated as a GCC plugin.

Your example shows (probably) a [mangled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) C++ name. You could use `nm -C` to get it unmangled. And later write a GCC plugin to find all the [GIMPLE](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GIMPLE.html) `CALL` instructions using it.

Writing a GCC plugin may take some time, in particular if you are not familiar with [GCC internals](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint).